# How to update score dynamically using jquery and php without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Using the codes below, I want to update the leaderboard `<div id='result'></div>` whenever the score (json) changes in `score.php`.

I tried wrapping the whole `$.getJSON` query with `setInterval` but its duplicating the list items everytime the `setInterval` fires instead of just updating the list items with the new score json object.

So far , the code works when you refresh the page but I want it to update dynamically.

Any ideas how to achieve the desired effects that I want? TIA

index.php

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result').html('<ul></ul>');

    setInterval(function(){

        $.getJSON('score.php', function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i){
                $('#result > ul').append('<li>'+i+' : '+data[i]+'</li>');
            });
        });

    },1000);
});
```

score.php

```
<?php
$result = [
"player1"=>5,
"player2"=>20,
"player3"=>7
];
arsort($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

// output

```
player2 : 20
player3 : 7
player1 : 5
```

note: I have modified script.js to show the problem. the issue is that every time `setInterval` fires up, the list- items is duplicating which is not what i want.

really all i want is that the original list items will just update to reflect the changes in score.php everytime a player gets higher score, it shows in the leaderboard.

UPDATE: this is already resolved as per @Peekayy and @user26409021 answers below. but I don't know which one is more efficient so I will leave this question for a couple of days to gain more votes for the two answers and then I will choose an answer. thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

For each setInterval you append new `<li>` items corresponding to the JSON result. This without clearing the existing nodes. That's why it seems to be duplication items.

You have to clear the #result children with $('#result > ul').empty(); before adding the new nodes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result').append('<ul></ul>');
    $.getJSON('score.php', function(data){
        $('#result > ul').empty();
        $.each(data, function(i){
            $('#result > ul').addClass('result-list').append('<li>'+i+' : '+data[i]+'</li>');
        });
    });
});
```

Also, i wonder if the use of `addClass('result-list')` for each player score is relevant. You should do it only once i think to make it cleaner.

Final code i'd suggest :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var resultList = $('#result').append('<ul></ul>');
    resultList.addClass('result-list');
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('score.php', function(data){
            resultList.empty();
            $.each(data, function(i){
                resultList.append('<li>'+i+' : '+data[i]+'</li>');
            });
        });
    }, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need isn't `.append` but `.html` which will remove previous element from the div.. By doing so, you won't have duplicate entries.

```
$('#result').html('<ul></ul>');

setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON('score.php', function(data){
        $('#result').html('<ul></ul>');//reset here..
        $.each(data, function(i){
            $('#result > ul').append('<li>'+i+' : '+data[i]+'</li>');
        });
    });

},1000);
```

Comment: tried your suggestion but it doesnt work. also i edit the code above to show the real problem.